# appengine : pointing a domain to subdomain

Tags: google-app-engine, dns, google-apps, cname

can i point

http://www.mycustomdomain.com

to

http://myapp.appspot.com

using cname record or other gimmicks ? I do not want to use google apps.

it is possible ?

Comment: As @Wooble says, the only way to do this is via Google Apps - and there's no reason not to, since it's free and you don't need to use it for anything else if you don't want to.

Answer (score 5):

If you don't want to use Google Apps, you could serve redirects to your appspot address from another HTTP server somewhere. You cannot do this with DNS settings alone without Google Apps; the server needs to know which application to serve for a given request URL, and if the domain isn't a Google Apps domain, you can't configure this. Note that if you use redirects, the user will not see your domain name when visiting your app; once they're redirected they'll be viewing at an appspot.com address.

Are you aware that there's a free level of Google Apps service, that you could set up only to serve App Engine apps?